# vcpkg error : How would I fix Build error?

Tags: windows, build

Hey I am running into an issue with a vcpkg install. I am running windows and using vcpkg to install ogre. the issue I am running into is jasper install. Though I am not sure where to begin. Any help?

Windows 64bit

error: building jasper:x86-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED

````
Stored binary cache: C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\vcpkg\archives\ca\ca82ed304929649a647732081047dbc99f15bad1a06d480a80d0c5918cb89564.zip
Elapsed time to handle opengl:x86-windows: 310.5 ms
Installing 22/36 jasper:x86-windows...
Building jasper[core,opengl]:x86-windows...
-- Downloading https://github.com/mdadams/jasper/archive/fe00207dc10db1d7cc6f2757961c5c6bdfd10973.tar.gz -> mdadams-jasper-fe00207dc10db1d7cc6f2757961c5c6bdfd10973.tar.gz...
-- Extracting source C:/src/vcpkg/downloads/mdadams-jasper-fe00207dc10db1d7cc6f2757961c5c6bdfd10973.tar.gz
-- Using source at C:/src/vcpkg/buildtrees/jasper/src/6bdfd10973-cdf68d9a44.clean
-- Found external ninja('1.10.2').
-- Configuring x86-windows
-- Building x86-windows-dbg
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_build_process.cmake:158 (message):
    Command failed: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/cmake.exe --build . --config Debug --target install -- -v -j9
    Working Directory: C:/src/vcpkg/buildtrees/jasper/x86-windows-dbg
    See logs for more information:
      C:\src\vcpkg\buildtrees\jasper\install-x86-windows-dbg-out.log

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  installed/x64-windows/share/vcpkg-cmake/vcpkg_cmake_build.cmake:112 (vcpkg_execute_build_process)
  installed/x64-windows/share/vcpkg-cmake/vcpkg_cmake_install.cmake:41 (vcpkg_cmake_build)
  ports/jasper/portfile.cmake:34 (vcpkg_cmake_install)
  scripts/ports.cmake:146 (include)


error: building jasper:x86-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED
Please ensure you're using the latest port files with `git pull` and `vcpkg update`.
Then check for known issues at:
    https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+in%3Atitle+jasper
You can submit a new issue at:
    https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/new?template=report-package-build-failure.md&title=[jasper]+Build+error
Include '[jasper] Build error' in your bug report title, the following version information in your bug description, and attach any relevant failure logs from above.
    vcpkg-tool version: 2022-05-05-67e17c1782801cf481be9ac0b3765dff3e4bdeb8
    vcpkg-scripts version: 0cf5b4305 2022-05-13 (2 days ago) ```
````

Comment: @DrMoishePippik No the log output is not shown below the error in my terminal & symbols have not been installed. Could you explain to me how i would install them?

Comment: See the link in my comment.

Comment: 1. Is the log output (See logs for more information: C:\src\vcpkg\buildtrees\jasper\install-x86-windows-dbg-out.log) shown below? If not, add that to the question. 2. Since you're making the debug version, have the symbols been installed: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-symbols

Comment: "Please ensure you're using the latest port files with `git pull` and `vcpkg update`" Have you done this?

Comment: @DavidPostill yes I have done that. I got the same error.